# Firebase Function Data Type of "data" in onCall function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I thought i had a simple question but it seems to be somewhat harder and the documentation does not help alot.

What exactly is the type of 'data' in "functions.https.onCall((data, context) {});"

I thought it varies between a simple value, a map or a list.
But even if i call the function with a map object and try to delete a key from it, it fails because it isn't a map.

It also can't be immutable and casting it to a map doesn't work too.

So whatever it is, i just want to remove a key from it. Does anyone know the datatype so i am able to find the correct function?

Comment: to delete, you can use `delete <objectname>.<key>`

Comment: @Delwinn can you give an example? data.delete(key) does not work because '.delete' is not defined on 'object'. That's why i am here :)

Comment: @Delwinn thanks, i'm now getting what you've meant. this works. I hate typescript.

Comment: Yuki, glad to hear that the issue is resolved, maybe you can post the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.

Answer (score 0):

As @Delwinn stated out, the 'data' object seems to be a 'json object' (if this is a type in typescript) and not a map.

to delete a value from this object, a plain line like

```
delete json[key]
```

will do the job.
And yes, 'delete' is written like an operator and not a function.